# Not able to retrieve data from datastore using node

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple get request built using node, express to retrieve data from datastore. I am not able to get back the results. 'get' request async call is stuck. Not sure what is happening.

```
const express = require('express');
const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

const app = express();

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'xxx';

// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
  projectId: projectId,
  keyFilename: '/Masters-LUC/spring-2019/internship/service-keys/xxx.json'
});

const query = datastore
  .createQuery('approvals')
  .filter('status', '=', 'yes');

app.get("/api/get", (req, res, next) => {
  query.run().then(([documents]) => {
    documents.forEach(doc => console.log(doc));
  });

});

module.exports = app;
```

I re-wrote the same using async function. The below is working. Why not the above?

```
// Retrieve data from datastore
async function quickStart() {
  // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
  const projectId = 'xxx';

  // Creates a client
  const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: '/Masters-LUC/spring-2019/internship/service- 
keys/xxx.json'
  });

  const query = datastore
  .createQuery('approvals')
  .filter('status', '=', 'yes');

  const [approvals] = await datastore.runQuery(query);
  console.log('Tasks:');
  approvals.forEach(task => console.log(task));
}
quickStart().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

The two things I notice that is different between your two functions.  In the first you reuse the query object across function invocations.  Query objects should not be reused.

The second thing I notice is that you don't use res that's passed into your function parameter to app.get().

Comment: Thank you @Jim Morrison. Your second point made sense. I made use of the response object and modified the code. It worked. I will post the modified code. However, i did not get your first point - "reuse the query object across function invocations". I am creating a query object first and then making use of the same only once in the get call. Correct me if i am wrong!!

Comment: I see you fixed the code below.  However, in your original code the query object was created outside of the function passed to app.get().  That means that object would be reused across calls to your function.  As your fixed code shows, you now create the query object inside your function that you pass to app.get().

Answer (score 0):

Modified working code -

```
    app.get("/api/approvals/", (req, res, next) => {
    const query = datastore
    .createQuery('approvals');

    query.run().then((approvals) => {
    approvals.forEach(appr => console.log(appr)); // This is used to log results on console for verification

    // loading results on the response object to be used later by client
    res.status(200).json(
      {
        message: "Request was processed successfully!",
        approvals : approvals
      }
    );
  })
})
```